# How to record audio from Flash games

Tags: firefox, osx-lion, flash-player, audio-recording

I would like to record audio from Flash games that I play on my browser.
Is that possible?

My OS is OS X Lion.
I use Firefox as my browser, but I don't mind using anything else if it will get the job done.

Solution should be free.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this free tool: [Freecorder](http://www.freecorder.com/).

Comment: thanks but it seems that the free version is not suitable for my needs. forgot to mention that i'm looking for a free solution. updating post.